# How can I create realistic noisy data from distributions?

Tags: distributions, density-function, noise, synthetic-data

I want to create synthetic data from stitched distributions in order to test some models on them (for example Gaussian stitched with a GPD at quantile q).

I'm currently simply sampling N*q points from the Gaussian, and (1-q)*N points from the GPD.

The issue is that there's a clear seperation in the resulting PDF, making it very unrealistic.

[image: Example with a stitched gaussian/GPD at the quantile 0.8]

The parameters of both distributions are fixed and I do not want to have to change them in order to smoothen the PDF.

What is the best way to add noise to the data in order to create a more realistic PDF that is not clearly a simple stitching of the two distributions ?

Should I just add a random noise (but what kind ?) to the discretized PDF and normalize it or is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Hm. If the parameters of both distributions are fixed, then this is just what it is. Your two component distributions are just so heavily different that the "stitching" will always be obvious. If this is an issue, then you might want to revisit the component distributions.

Comment: You say you don't want to smooth, but adding noise will do exactly that -- and it would increase the variance to boot.

Comment: I do want to smoothen it, but not by changing the parameters of my distributions. The stitching will still be visible, but I'd like to hide it a bit and more importantly, make it less smooth on the Gaussian and GPD part in order to make it harder to determine from which distribution each part respectively comes from

Comment: You could add a third component that "covers" the "stitching" region. Other than that or changing your distributions' parameters to make them more similar, I really don't see what you can do.

Comment: I think Stephan's solution makes considerably more sense than just "add noise", but for the life of me this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); there's likely a better solution to the underlying but unstated problem